# Adding XML element for before element with different value from previous element group

Tags: asp.net, xml

I have an XML file I am reading in the code-behind C# ASP.Net page which lists staff details and is organised according to the team they belong to. See below:

```
<user>
<firstname>Tony</firstname>
<surname>Smith</surname>
<team>Board A</team>
</user>
<user>
<firstname>Paula</firstname>
<surname>Ram</surname>
<team>Board A</team>
</user>
<user>
<firstname>Linda</firstname>
<surname>Smith</surname>
<team>Board b</team>
</user>
<user>
<firstname>Sam </firstname>
<surname>Peak</surname>
<team>Board b</team>
</user>
```

What I would like to do is the following:

```
<group>Board A</group>
<user>
<firstname>Tony</firstname>
<surname>Smith</surname>
<team>Board A</team>
</user>
<user>
<firstname>Paula</firstname>
<surname>Ram</surname>
<team>Board A</team>
</user>
<user>
<group>Board B</group>
<firstname>Linda</firstname>
<surname>Smith</surname>
<team>Board b</team>
</user>
<user>
<firstname>Sam </firstname>
<surname>Peak</surname>
<team>Board b</team>
</user>
```

So basically insert a new element with the name of the team  the the elements that follow it contain in the team element? I'm not sure if I'm malking any sense?

Ta.

Momo

Answer (score 0):

With xml it would be kind of redundant to use the structure of your second example, because you can already group your elements by team with xpath (or LINQ).  In XPATH:

```
"/user[team='Board b']"
```

if you have System.Xml.XmlNode

```
string currentGroup = "Board B"; //get this from some control
XmlNodeList groups = xdoc.SelectNodes(String.Format("/user[team='{0}']",currentGroup));
```

or if you have a System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator

```
string currentGroup = "Board B";
XPathNodeIterator groups = xNav.Select(String.Format("/user[team='{0}']",currentGroup));
```

Or you can place your "users" in the "group" element:

```
<group name="Board A">
    <user>
      <firstname>Tony</firstname>
      <surname>Smith</surname>
      <!-- <team>Board A</team> -->
    </user>
    <user>
      <firstname>Paula</firstname>
      <surname>Ram</surname>
    </user>
</group>
```

And then as an example of how to select them:

```
string currentGroup = "Board B";
XmlNodeList groups = xdoc.SelectNodes(String.Format("//user[parent::group/@name='{0}']",currentGroup));
```